# ListInstance with CustomSchema ignore field Resources

Tags: list, resources, custom-schema

I have [ListInstance element with CustomSchema attribute](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.cz/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-listinstance.html). In schema I use fields with resource display name.

But after creation of this list all fields are in default language without translation.

ListsInstance that use own ListDefinition are OK.

Have you ever met with this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can confirm this weird behavior.
ListInstances created from CustomSchema don't show the translated text, whereas ListInstances created from a custom ListDefinition do.